# Understanding the use of base64 vs UTF-8 to generate bytes objects from strings to be used as keys for encryption

Tags: encryption, utf-8, base64

I am slightly confused as to why we tend to use UTF-8 to encode strings to be used as keys in an encryption or key derivation scheme.

1. As far as I understand, UTF-8 is designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII and therefore at minimum generates 1 byte to cover the 128 code points of ASCII.
2. A user is unlikely to input, or be able to input, the first 33 special characters (NUL to SP) of the ASCII table and the DEL character at the very end, leaving a total of 34 never-used characters.
3. As a result, an attacker may (safely) assume that the key as encoded as bytes using UTF-8 will never include the forementioned characters.

Is it not better, from a cryptographic standpoint, to restrict the user to input characters used in base 64, namely a-z,A-Z,0-9,/,+ and force the user to use more characters as needed to match a given security policy?

Would you agree that this approach would generate a much wider range of values of bytes objects, namely 0x00-0xFF using base64 as opposed to 0x21-0x7E using UTF-8?

Comment: keys and passwords are different things. keys can be derived from passwords, of course. Passwords should be entered using the user's normal language, encoded to bytes using UTF-8, and then passed through a password-based key derivation function (PBKDF) like argon2 to generate a key. Restricting the character set for password to base-64 would only server to reduce the entropy in password, all other things being equal.

Comment: As it stands your question is off topic, and liable to closed, for a couple of reasons: [1] It is explicitly inviting opinions with the use of the phrases _"Is it not better...?"_ and _"Would you agree...?"_ [2] You are asking a hypothetical question; you have no actual problem to be solved. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for clarification. Can you reframe/reword your question to ask about a specific issue that is causing you a problem? (This isn't a criticism of your question per se; it's just that's it's not suitable for SO.)